# How to format code snippet in Javadoc with @ and { symbols inside?

Tags: java, javadoc

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * &#64;XmlRootElement
 * public final class Page &#123;
 * &#125;
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

I'm expecting it to be formatted like:

```
@XmlRootElement
public final class Page {
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
&#64;XmlRootElement
public final class Page &#123;
&#125;
```

Replacing these HTML entities with real symbols (`@`, `{`, `}`) leads to javadoc warnings and absolutely incorrect formatting. What is a workaround?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is how it finally works for me:

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * &#64;XmlRootElement
 * public final class Page {
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

Comment: Your answer works for me. THX.
If use "{@literal @}Override", I have to remove one space before "{@literal @}Override" to line up.

Answer (score 31):

```
<pre>
<code>
{@literal@}Override
public String toString() {
    return "blah";
}
</code>
</pre>
```

This works for me.

Comment: I had to add a space between `@literal` and `@`, like so: `{@literal @}Override`

Answer (score 7):

wrap your code snippet with `<pre><code></code></pre>`. These are special HTML tags that allow you to forget about escaping of special characters.

Comment: Huh. There is nothing in the definition of `pre` or `code` which escapes special characters. They only change the font and the whitespace interpretation. (Also, `@` and `{` might get interpreted by Javadoc before the HTML browser even gets them.)

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 18 ([JEP 413](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/413)) you may use `@snippet` tag:

```
/**
 * -- ex: looping through List of Map objects --
 * {@snippet :
 * @XmlRootElement
 * public final class Page {
 * }
 * }
 */
```

Comment: You can also use the same syntax in Java 8+ with this maven doclet plugin https://github.com/jtulach/codesnippet4javadoc

Answer (score 0):

It is old question but I figured out why it was not working for me.

This was not working:

```
<pre>{@code 
@Autowired
```

But when all written in one line it works.

```
<pre>
{@code @Autowired
```